# Does SBT support init scripts similar to what Gradle has?

Tags: gradle, sbt

I need to shim some SBT projects with custom logic during the build process. I can achieve this with Gradle using init scripts, is there a similar mechanism for SBT?

Comment: I don't think you can do exactly what gradle init script does. All custom logic in sbt is provided via `AutoPlugin`. This means that you need to build it, publish it and then `addSbtPlugin` it

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a Gradle init script I've been able to find is placing scripts under the `~/.sbt/` directory, or inside of `~/.sbtrc` as described in the [Best Practices](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Best-Practices.html) page on SBT's website.

> ### `project/` vs. `~/.sbt/`
>
> Anything that is necessary for building the project should go in `project/`. This includes things like the web plugin. `~/.sbt/` should contain local customizations and commands for working with a build, but are not necessary. An example is an IDE plugin.
>
> ### Local settings
>
> There are two options for settings that are specific to a user. An example of such a setting is inserting the local Maven repository at the beginning of the resolvers list:
>
> ```
> resolvers := {
>   val localMaven = "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
>   localMaven +: resolvers.value
> }
> ```
>
> Put settings specific to a user in a global `.sbt` file, such as `$HOME/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt`. These settings will be applied to all projects.
> Put settings in a .sbt file in a project that isn’t checked into version control, such as `<project>/local.sbt`. sbt combines the settings from multiple .sbt files, so you can still have the standard `<project>/build.sbt` and check that into version control.
>
> ### `.sbtrc`
>
> Put commands to be executed when sbt starts up in a .sbtrc file, one per line. These commands run before a project is loaded and are useful for defining aliases, for example. sbt executes commands in `$HOME/.sbtrc` (if it exists) and then `<project>/.sbtrc` (if it exists).